# Android screen orientation data lose prevention

Tags: android, service, settings, screen-orientation

I am trying to stop my app from resetting whenever the user flips the screen. I don't really want to set it to portrait permanently.

My problem is I have settings which erase and a service which stops each time the screen flips. I would like to keep things as they are regardless of the screen orientation.

Comment: When you flip the phone around your activity is recreated. We need more info to help you here --- are you using standard Android preferences and the recommend service paradigm http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html ? Or are you using some custom "services" and preference stores?

Comment: I am using standard services. Preferences is not something I am using presently because I don't know how I can use it to tell the service to keep running even when the the activity is recreated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Activity in your AndroidManifest, set the following:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

This tells your Activity to not "re-create" itself on screen orientation changes or keyboard change state

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data by using :

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

return the data you want to save.

In the `onCreate` function you can check if there is any data saved by doing the following

```
final Object data = (Object) getLastNonConfigurationInstance());
    if (data == null) {
        //Retrieve data
    }else{
        //Use the saved data
        settings = data;
        }
```

You can read about [this topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) at the Android Dev Guide :