# How to handle Android portrait and landscape in code?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application in two languages (Arabic and English), When the user press on a Button in the first activity it views another activity contains (Timer, array of strings and many different values)
When the user change between portrait and landscape the values lost, How to handle this problem (Keeping the values and the objects)

Kind Regards,

Comment: This answer was allready solved

[See this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223582/android-screen-orientation-data-lose-prevention/7224074#7224074

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you rotate a device your activity is restarted. To avoid this, you must handle the orientation change yourself. To do this, you must add the configuration to your manifest XML ([android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges)) and override the [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) function in your activity.

[Here's an example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) from the Android documentation. Implementing this will allow you to retain the state (and variables) in your activity during an orientation change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply,

I know it is restarted, But how to prevent that? if we cannot prevent that, what should I do in the onConfigurationChanged method?

Comment: When you add in your manifest that your activity handles the configChanges for orientation changes, and you override the onConfiguriationChanged then YOU control what happens during the orientation change, and your activity is not restarted. Implement the example and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml File

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Follow along the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add `android:screenOrientation="potrait"` to this code  `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">`, it should turn out to be something like this:
`<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >`

This will resolve the issue !